# Celery - Asynchronous Task Chaining

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, redis, celery

I am trying to develop a proof-of-concept to for asynchronous task chaining on using celery with redis as broker.

The program is Flask API with /run and three functions that need to run as async tasks such that return from a(), is argument of b() and return b() is argument for c() which writes the data into a mongodb collection through a collection object 'collection'.

```
@celery.task
def a(param):
    print("Original: {0}".format(param))
    print("Inside Task 1")
    param.update({"timestamp_A":str(datetime.timestamp), "result_A":True})
    print(param)
    return param

@celery.task
def b(param):
    print("Inside Task 2")
    param.update({"timestamp_B":str(datetime.timestamp), "result_B":True})
    print(param)
    return param

@celery.task
def c(param):
    print("Inside Task 3")
    collection.insert(dict(param))
    print("Output Saved to DB")


@app.route('/run', methods = ['GET'])
def run():
    if request.method != 'GET':
        return "HTTP Method not allowed"

    if request.method == 'GET':
        T = 1000
        for num in range(0, T):
            ds = {"test": num}
            chain(a.s(ds) | b.s() | c.s()).apply_async()
        return "Process Complete"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

With the above code task chaining works i.e. a() gets executed with with its parameter, but for function b() to get executed it waited for the entire data to be queued in a() first and only then did it execute b(). I need that soon as any task a() gets executed it should be handed to b() and so on..
Anyone has any pointers on where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something, but it seems like the simplest way to do this is to just call the next task at the end of the previous task.

```
@celery.task
def a(arg):
  ret = calc(arg)
  b.apply_async(ret)

@celery.task
def b(arg):
  ret = calc(arg)
  c.apply_async(ret)

@celery.task
def c(arg):
  ret = calc(arg)
  mongo.store(ret)
```

This does NOT allow you to call a in the loop sometimes and sometimes not, but you can wrap the task in an outer task that runs the inside part synchronously.

Comment: Is it normal to spawn background tasks from within a background job? While it does seem to give the control on process flow it doesn't seem very efficient as if b() is long running task, it will bind the process id running task a() also, and the same for c(). Wouldn't this mean while task a is completed celery can't give a completion signal and keep occupying resource for it?

Comment: no, apply_async() has the same effect if called within a task as without- it sends a message to the task queue to schedule a job on the next available worker. It WOULD mean that you can't use results of 'a' to track completion of 'c', if you were relying on the celery results api you would have to pass back the task id of the spawned tasks. (however, I have also never used the results api, instead relying on logging and the signals generated by the tasks in the data stores)

Comment: The above procedure worked for me, and solves the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

From the description you provided, it sounds like you should be using a [chain](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives). A chain does exactly what you are asking for, lumps tasks together, passing the return value of each task to the next task in the chain.

Comment: Hey @MrName , yeah right! I have used chain as you can see in the code. The trouble I was facing is not having control over which task gets executed in which order. .
For instance three tasks get spawned with id a1, a2, a3 and so on for function a() and there is a possibility of tasks up to a20 to be spawned, I need task control to spawn a task b2 for function b() if task a2 is successful. Is there a way of understanding how the control flows?

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Sorry, didn't notice the `chain` call in your code. Good question, will see if I can come up with anything helpful.